# socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known in flask app

Tags: sockets, flask, openshift, uwsgi

I followed the steps mentioned in https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-flask.html
to create a sample flask application.

When I am trying to run wsgi.py on my local mac machine. I am getting the following error.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "wsgi.py", line 24, in <module>
>     httpd = make_server('localhost', 10000, application)
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py",
> ```
>
> line 144, in make_server
>           server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py",
>   line 419, in **init**
>           self.server_bind()
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py",
>   line 48, in server_bind
>           HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py",
>   line 108, in server_bind
>           SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py",
>   line 430, in server_bind
>           self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
>   line 224, in meth
>           return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
>       socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: Can you please also show _your code_ that is causing the error? My suspicion is you are passing `'localhost'` and `10000` as separate parameters as opposed to a tuple `('localhost', 10000)` as expected, but can't say so without your actual code that's causing this exception

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    httpd = make_server('localhost', 8051, application)
    httpd.serve_forever()

Comment: As you found the lines to create ``httpd`` object and run it should only be run on your local machine and should be guarded by check of ``__name__`` being ``__main__``. When deploying as a ``wsgi.py`` file to OpenShift, it will run under mod_wsgi and all it wants is that there is a WSGI application entry point in the file called ``application``. You should not start your own WSGI server if using ``wsgi.py``.

Comment: Please take a look at this documentation https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-flask.html . I am using the same code.

Comment: Sorry, confusion on my part. I thought you were getting this on OpenShift. Didn't see that you said on your own machine. Try changing 'localhost' to an empty string instead. I have seen in some situations that MacOS X doesn't like being told to bind to 'localhost'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but if I am changing 'localhost' to an empty string then I am not able to access http://localhost:8051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem for me was using a non-standard port. Had to define my port separately from the host.

```
    self.config = {
        'user': 'root',
        'password': 'root',
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'port': 8889,
        'database': 'ET_Toolbox',
        'charset': 'utf8'
    }
```